# Store several jobs and keep them running in the background

Tags: python, apscheduler

**Context**: I'm trying to create 3 schedules - one that gathers stock data daily, weekly and monthly (and then push this data onto MySQL).

**Question**: Is there a way to run these 3 jobs on the background? I'm using visual code studio and when I close the IDE, the scheduler seems to stop running in the background. I was testing it out by saving certain data in a csv file, but this only seems to work when I have the IDE and terminal open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What APScheduler allows you to do is simply to "delay" actions to match a predefined schedule, not to run a task as a daemon (or in back ground, if you prefer).

From here, there are two ways to go. Either you manually start a daemon within python [as explained here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/), or you let your OS launch the application as a daemon for you.

The more general solution would probably be to let your code create a daemon, even though (at least on Linux), it's likely to be easier to let your OS handle it.

However, since I don't know what your OS is, and since starting a daemon from python isn't that hard, I would recommend to go for the python-handled way.

Comment: If your python script working well while open IDE, then you can search application scheduler in windows 10 operating system and select your python file and follow instruction. I think it work 100%. And another way you can open command prompt as administrator and then go to your python file path after path just type "python" then space then your pythin file name with extension and enter then check if work then make it as batch file. And add into startup program